# Charge DC battery with a DC motor?

Tags: motor, battery-charging, dc

Is it possible to charge a DC battery with a DC motor by turning the shaft of the DC motor? I know it is possible to charge an AC battery by turning the shaft of the AC motor. If it is possible, how would you do it?

Comment: AC batteries don't exist. And how to do it depends on the specs of the motor and battery.

Comment: I was thinking of a standard car battery (12V) and a 12V 250W motor

Comment: Now that we know it's a 12V lead acid battery, and 12V 250W DC motor, you are still missing a lot of info on the motor. However, car batteries are best charged with car alternators.

Comment: I was thinking of this battery [link] (https://www.amazon.com/Reduction-Electric-Sprocket-Bicycle-Scooter/dp/B08HQVG9VQ/ref=sr_1_9?crid=1A6KZYKUJJM56&keywords=12v+dc+motor+high+torque&qid=1677525378&sprefix=12v+dc+motor+high+torque%2Caps%2C123&sr=8-9)

Comment: This question is essentially asking for tuition on motors. It's a Q&A site, rather than discussion forum, and can't be a personal tutorial service, which is effectively what you're asking for. VTC for those reasons. You'll find plenty of detailed and free documentation on motors available on the internet for you to research and learn from. Hope you can see how the site works but refer to other high-voted questions for examples of what's well-regarded here. Thanks.

Comment: Ok sounds good. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use a DC motor with permanent magnets as a generator. If its output voltage is sufficiently high, it can charge a battery. But it's also possible to destroy a battery when you charge it in such an uncontrolled manner. So, be careful.

> how would you do it?

I would not connect the motor directly to a battery. Instead, I would place a charger (such as a DC-DC converter that is current limited and has an adjustable top voltage, matched to the battery voltage) between the generator and the battery. It depends a lot on the type of battery.